# A sentence from Nietzsche's essay "On truth and lies in a Non-moral Sense"

Tags: sentence, phrase-meaning

I have read and reread following lines many times but can't seem to make sense out of it. Any help is appreciated.

> "And just as every porter wants to have an admirer, so even the proudest of men, the philosopher, **supposes** that he sees on all sides the eyes of the universe telescopically focused upon his action and thought."

I am having problem understanding after the word "suppose". I am confused who sees on all sides (sentence suggests that the proud men to me)? But then sentence doesn't appear to be well defined. Does it say that proud men thinks all the eyes of the world are fixated on him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, the word "suppose" means "believe"; see [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suppose):

> b (1) :  to hold as an opinion :  believe [they *supposed* they were early]
>
> (2) :  to think probable or in keeping with the facts [seems reasonable to *suppose* that he would profit]

So the key phrase:

> "...the proudest of men, the philosopher, supposes that he sees on all sides the eyes of the universe telescopically focused upon his action and thought."

...may be treated as:

> "...the philosopher supposes (believes) that he sees (on all sides) the eyes of the universe."

Note that the philosopher *is* the "proudest of men" in this sentence; they are the same person.

So, yes, the "proudest of men" believes that the whole universe is fixated on him.

Comment: Aah!  it makes sense! Thank you! I don't know why I got confused in linking seeing to eyes even though there is no such link! Thanks again!

Comment: likes to believe, assume , imagine that he is some center of attention, adulation, admiration, cynosure of all eyes and so on ... that he in fact enjoys

Answer (score 2):

> "And just as every porter wants to have an admirer, so even the proudest of men, the philosopher, supposes that he sees on all sides the eyes of the universe telescopically focused upon his action and thought."

I may be wrong, but Nietzsche seems to be saying that just as the supposedly humblest of men (viz., the porter, or [a person employed to carry burdens, especially an attendant who carries travelers' baggage at a hotel or transportation station](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/porter)) wants to be seen and admired, so too does the proudest man want to be seen and admired.

The difference between the desire of the humble man and the desire of the proud man is a matter of degree. While the humble man is satisfied in knowing at least one person sees him and admires him (for whatever reason, perhaps for the professional way in which he carries someone's baggage), the proud person, on the other hand, is satisfied only when many, many people see him and admire him.

Moreover, he doesn't need just an admiring glance, but he needs continually the admiring and focused attention of all kinds of people, whether his peers, whether those whom he considers to be his "inferiors," or whether anyone, really.

For the humble man, his desire is really a search for dignity. For the proud man, his desire is not for dignity, which he has in truckloads, but for the feeling of superiority.

Whether Nietzsche's "take" on philosophers is accurate or not, all people, regardless of their station in life want to be noticed and admired for something. In other words, we all long for significance. That longing takes an ugly turn, however, when it morphs into a superiority complex, complete with delusions of grandeur!

In Christian circles, the saying goes, "The ground is level at the cross." I like that, and I think it speaks volumes to the blatently narcissistic age in which we live.

Comment: Your answer surely has depth! Thank you for your views. Can you explain what that Christian actually means?

Comment: I meant Christian saying.Pardon me.

Comment: @MustafaMotani: Certainly. The cross (t) is the central symbol of the Christian faith. It represents, of course, the death of Christ on a Roman cross 2000 years ago. According to Christian belief, Christ bore the sins of the world on that cross, and each person in the world, porter and philosopher alike, needs to embrace it, by faith, because of the sins they have committed. No one is exempt, since all of us have sinned. THAT is why the ground is level at the cross of Jesus Christ. No one can say, apart from God's grace, "I am sinless and do not need forgiveness." We're all in the same boat!

Comment: @MustafaMotani: By the way, if you are not satisfied with a comment you have made, simply click on the word "edit" next to your comment to change it. You have about 5 minutes to edit your comment. After 5 minutes, you can eliminate the comment by hovering with your cursor over the area to the right of the word "edit." When the red X appears, click on it and the comment will disappear. You can then start over again, if you wish.

Comment: Thank you for your time in explaining, and yeah I will do that next time. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty correct in your assumption of what this sentence means. The author is comparing the proud to porters, saying that everyone wants an admirer. Nietzsche goes a step further to say outright that philosophers are the proudest men, and that they want the universe to admire them.

Onward, to definitions. To *suppose* something is to assume it as truth. Nietzsche here is saying that philosophers (the proudest men) already assume the universe admires them.

As for "all sides", the philosopher sees all sides around him looking on. Going back to that pride (a pretty common motif for Nietzsche), the philosopher sees himself at the center, and all sides around that center are focused on him.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and help! I finally understood it. It seems you have read Nietzsche.